# Некоректно работает дебаггер в PHPStorm: Debug session was finished without being paused

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

При дебаге PHPStorm пишет:

> Debug session was finished without being paused
>   It may be caused by path mappings misconfiguration or not synchronized local and remote projects.
>   To figure out the problem check path mappings configuration for 'basecrm' server at PHP|Servers or enable Break at first line in PHP scripts option (from Run menu).
>   Do not show again.

Причём для отдельной страницы в проекте; на остальных контрольные точки работают, и в других проектах тоже все ок.

Всё что выдаёт Google прочитал, но вроде никакой ответ не подходит. Пересоздал все настройки в PHPStorm по новой — не помогло; глянул в `.ini`-файл — тоже всё ОК.

Соответсвия стояли, брекпоинты тоже работали как положено. Но в один момент все перестало работать. Незнаю просто удалил этот файл пересоздал его по новой и все заработало. Магия PHP:)

Comment: У меня такое было, когда в шторме не было задано соответствия между урлами и исполняемыми файлами. Он, собственно, и предлагает это сделать в настройках в `PHP -> Servers`.

Comment: Тут непонятно. Причин может быть масса. Например программа просто не доходит до Вашего кода, поскольку существует return или die где-то выше. Или не срабатывает условие. Или точка останова поставлена там, где нет исполняемого кода (комментарий, единственная скобка и т.д)

Comment: Xdebug работает нормально и PhpStorm, как видите, принимает от сервера данные от XDebug. Однако не может сопоставить данные с сервера и ваши локальные и сообщает вот в этой строчке  `o figure out the problem check path mappings configuration for 'basecrm' server ` о чем вам собственно и говорит уважаемый @etki  Проверьте пути до проекта на сервере и у вас на локальной машине. Если же проект у вас крутится на локальной машине, то проверьте нет ли симлинков. Возмоно вы используете докер? Там тоже надо сопоставить пути.
Ну и еще такая история может быть если у вас работает кэширование, например.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно ставить брейкпоинты в конец выражения.

**Не сработает**:

```
✓ $a = 
      1;
```

**Сработает**:

```
  $a = 
✓     1;
```